# Upgrading the PostgreSQL within QGIS

Tags: qgis, postgresql

Due to a vulnerability being flagged by Fortinet, I'm looking at upgrading the version of PostgreSQL that's used in our QGIS install. Is it possible to upgrade this without breaking QGIS, and how would be the best way of doing so?

Answer (score 3):

QGIS does not directly use PostgreSQL.

It would be a separate install.

Updating PostgreSQL will not impact QGIS directly, aside from for example saved connection in projects if you change the PostgreSQL port/user connection.